# Ubuntu Phone alternative browsers? VPN? Mysql client? Exchange client?

Tags: vpn, proxy, browser, alternative, ms-exchange

Got the Meizu MX4 with Ubuntu. But is there no alternative browser?
I'd like to install other browser(s) with possible proxy configuration settings?

The app store doesn't offer anything else?

How about a proper VPN client? Mysql client? Exchange client?

Can I just use apt-get in terminal mode?

Rgrds,
    Karel

Comment: Can I just use apt-get in terminal mode? Short answer no. Long answer..it has been asked before, have a look around. Generally speaking, your question is a bit broad and better fitted for a forum.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, Ubuntu touch phones are for early adopters that want hardware to develop and test new applications themselves …  It has most features that most phones have as well and some features that none have, but if you want Skype, MySQL, VLC, VNC, FireFox, … from the standard repositories, roll up your sleeves and start adapting them and publish them yourself.

### :-)

Comment: As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no other browser or connection manager with proxy setting for the moment.

On this french forum, one as post a non-optimal solution to configure a proxy: [link](http://ubuntuphone.fr/forum/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=14)

Not sure it is really helpful...